# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'save') + TypeORM + Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, repository, nestjs, typeorm

I'm still new to Unit Testing, TypeOrm, and NestJs. I currently have a user registration repository I'm trying to unit test. The feature works perfectly fine and I can register a user. But when I'm unit testing the repository I get the error **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'save')**.

This is my **user.repository.ts** file

```
import {
  ConflictException,
  InternalServerErrorException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { genSalt, hash } from 'bcryptjs';
import { omit } from 'lodash';
import { generate } from 'randomstring';
import { CreateUserDto } from 'src/dtos/user/create-user-dto';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@EntityRepository(User)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
  async register(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<object> {
    const {
      firstName,
      ... //other destructured fields here
    } = createUserDto;
    const salt = await genSalt();
    const user = this.create();
    user.firstName = firstName;
    ... // created user here
    try {
      await this.save(user);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === '23505') { //duplicate error
        console.log(error.message);
        // throw new ConflictException('Username or Password is Taken');
      } else {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException('THIS IS A 500 ERROR');
      }
    }
    let omitPasswordFromReturn = omit(user, ['password']);
    return omitPasswordFromReturn;
  }

  private async hashPassword(password: string, salt: string): Promise<string> {
    return hash(password, salt);
  }
}
```

And this is the **user.repository.spec.ts** file

```
import { ConflictException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { CreateUserDto } from 'src/dtos/user/create-user-dto';
import { UserRepository } from './user.repository';

const mockCreateUserDto: CreateUserDto = {
  firstName: 'Muhammad',
  ...
};

describe('UserRepository', () => {
  let userRepository;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [UserRepository],
    }).compile();

    userRepository = await module.get<UserRepository>(UserRepository);
  });

  describe('user registration', () => {
    let save;

    beforeEach(() => {
      save = jest.fn();
      userRepository.create = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ save });
    });  

    it('should be defined', () => {
      expect(userRepository.register).toBeDefined();
    })

    it('should sucessfully register user', async () => {
      save.mockResolvedValue(undefined);
      await expect(
        userRepository.register(mockCreateUserDto),
      ).resolves.not.toThrow();
    });

  });
});
```

I have searched typeOrm docs and on here at StackOverflow but nothing is helping.
I've really run out of ideas to try. any form of help is welcome

Comment: maybe you not init repository when run .save()

Comment: sorry, but I don't get what you mean by init repository